# Google Profile API Access in Android

Tags: android, google-api

Am using **google plus** sign in my android app and able to access **google profile** information with my registered email id, After that when i tried same app with new android phone am getting below error even though i registered with same email id.

```
Status{statusCode=DEVELOPER_ERROR, resolution=null}
```

I have placed google-services.json file also properly

Comment: while configuring project in google api console, are you declaring the SHA1 of your IDE(Studio/Eclipse) ? or providing release SHA fingerprint

Comment: I have declared bebug fingerprint as am stil working on debug app